# Probability and Set Theory

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, notation

When working with probabilities what does P(X,Y) means in means of set theory? Is it $P(X\cap Y)$ or $P(X\cup  Y)$ ?

I'm confused on this basic subject.

Mainly I'm searching for P(X,Y) where X=(U,V) and Y=(V,W), also U,V and W are independent.

Comment: You should say where you saw this. My guess is that $P(X,Y)$ stands for the probability of an unspecified (but perhaps fixed in some discussion) function of the events $X$ and $Y,$ of which $X \cap Y$ and $X \cup Y$ are two special cases.

Comment: thanks @Davel.Renfro I'm studying on Entropy and Information Content. Entropy is defined as $\sum P(X,Y)log(1/P(X,Y))$

Comment: Given what you said, try the google search [probability entropy P(x,y)](https://www.google.com/search?q=probability+entropy+P%28x%2Cy%29).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there's no universal connotation to $P(X,Y)$. It could mean one of the two things you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are events then I would regard $P(A,B)$ as meaning $P(A \cap B)$

i.e. the probability both events occur

In the expression for mutual information $$I(X;Y) = \sum_{y \in Y} \sum_{x \in X}
                 p(x,y) \log{ \left(\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)\,p(y)}
                              \right) }$$ that is the interpretation, since the events are $X=x$ and $Y=y$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $P(X=x \cap Y=y)= P(X=x)P(Y=y)$ so $\log \left(\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)\,p(y)}  \right)=0$ and the mutual information is zero as you might expect